# Using MapBox mobile client with GeoServer Protocols?

Tags: geoserver, mapbox

MapBox client is beauty and easy to use.

But it seems only support their own protocols (*GeoJSON & KML & TileJSON*).

GeoServer Only support WCS & WFS & WMS & TMS & WMS-C & WMTS

I am using GeoServer as a map server.

How can I make GeoServer and MapBox works together?

Answer (score 2):

You can render sources from GeoServer into Mapbox.js as well as Mapbox-GL.js.

Mapbox.js is simply a leaflet plugin, so you have access to all the leaflet goodness at your disposal. If you want to render a GeoServer layer via WMS (for example) simply use: [TileLayer.WMS](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-wms)

If you are using Mapbox-GL.js, you can create a new map source of type 'geojson', see this [implementation example](https://github.com/gem/oq-platform/blob/master/openquakeplatform/openquakeplatform/irv/static/irv/js/irv_viewer.js#L1102)

Answer (score 2):

I come cross this problem and I find a solution.Since you publish a vector tile map service by geoservice vector tile plugin;the source you set in mapbox-gl
is [image]

You can see more datails on http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/mbstyle/source.html

I first find some quzz about using pbf in mapbox-gl;I tried again and again;
but the damn geomotery doesn't show up;I trie reset the gridset and it doesn't
work either;

My final code is like this:

```
 var simple = {
        "version": 8,
        "sources": {
            "osm": {
                "type": "vector",
                "tiles": ["http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?REQUEST=GetTile&SERVICE=WMTS&VERSION=1.0.0&LAYER=putian:buildings&STYLE=&TILEMATRIX=EPSG:900913:{z}&TILEMATRIXSET=EPSG:900913&FORMAT=application/x-protobuf;type=mapbox-vector&TILECOL={x}&TILEROW={y}"]
                //"tiles": ["http://TegolaServerHost:8082/maps/zoning/{z}/{x}/{y}.vector.pbf"]
            }
        },
        "layers": [
            {
                "id": "background",
                "type": "background",
                "paint": {
                    "background-color": "#ffffff"
                }
            }, {
                "id": "buildings",
                "type": "fill",
                "source": "osm",
                "source-layer": "buildings",
                "filter": ["==", "$type", "Polygon"],
                "paint": {
                    "fill-color": "#444443"
                }
            }
        ]
    };

    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: simple,
        zoom: 13,
        pitch:50,
        center: [119.30603, 26.03024]
    });
```

since I spent lot of time on it,I think this may  be helpful for somebody else.

Comment: thats actually useful!